# How to pass multi parameters to Angular router?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I know we can do this like:

```
    { path:'/entity/:id/:action', component: EntityComponent }
```

However, I want to do something for path like:

```
    { path: '/entity/:id/sub-entity/:id2', component SubEntityComponent }
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

-------- updated ------

how to do both:

```
{ path: 'entity/:id/sub-entity/:id2', component: SubEntityComponent }
```

and

```
{ path: 'entity/:id/sub-obj/:id2, component: SubObjComponent' }
```

??

Thanks

Comment: those 2 ids are ment to be the same?

Comment: `{ path: '/entity/:id/sub-entity/:subid', component SubEntityComponent }` what is wrong with that ?

Comment: the parameters must be given unique names unless you want them to hold same value. Answer provided by @Antoniossss should work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a small typo with quotes in your second path:

```
{ path: 'entity/:id/sub-obj/:id2', component: SubObjComponent }
```

You can bind RouterLink like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/entity', id, 'sub-entity', id2]">SubEntityComponent</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/entity', id, 'sub-obj', id2]">SubObjComponent</a>
```

Check demo [**HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-parameters-b1fvkj?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts).

Comment: Thank you! [words patch][words patch][words patch]

Answer (score 1):

```
const routes: Routes  = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'entity/:id/sub-entity/:id2',
        component: SubEntityComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/entity/:id/sub-entity/:id2',
        component SubEntityComponent
    }
];


// in component:

// '/entity/:id/:action'
const id; // your param
const action; // your action
this.router.navigate(['entity', id, action]);

// 'entity/:id/sub-entity/:id2'
const id; // your first param
const id2; // your second param
this.router.navigate(['entity', id, 'sub-entity', id2]);
```

Comment: Thanks your for your answer! This helps me a lot. however your answer is a bit of late than abdul, but this is correct answer as well.

Comment: glad to help anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

in the file routes.ts

```
{ path: 'myUrlpath/:id1/:id2', component: componentToGoTo},
```

To call router

```
this.router.navigate(['myUrlPath/'+"someId"+"/"+"anotherID"]);
```

Comment: did you really read my question? but thanks for your post anyway.